# position() function brings me wrong data

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am using Selenium and Java to write a test, I have a DOM below:

```
<body>
    <div class='t'><span>1</span></div> 
    <div class='t'></div> 
    <div class='t'><span>2</span></div> 
    <div class='t'><span>3</span></div> 
    <div class='t'><span>4</span></div> 
    <div class='t'><span>5</span></div> 
    <div class='t'><span>6</span></div> 
    <div class='t'><span>7</span></div> 
</body>
```

why the result is the same for both:

```
//div[position()>1 and @class='t' and .//span ]
```

and

```
//div[position()>2 and @class='t' and .//span ]
```

and the result is:

```
<div class="t">
<span>2</span>
</div>

<div class="t">
<span>3</span>
</div>

<div class="t">
<span>4</span>
</div>

<div class="t">
<span>5</span>
</div>

<div class="t">
<span>6</span>
</div>

<div class="t">
<span>7</span>
</div>
```

my expectation for the first xpath is the same but for the second one I think it should be:

```
<div class="t">
<span>3</span>
</div>

<div class="t">
<span>4</span>
</div>

<div class="t">
<span>5</span>
</div>

<div class="t">
<span>6</span>
</div>

<div class="t">
<span>7</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I jus figured out that it the xpath should be `//div[ @class='t' and .//span ][position()>2]` so it first selects all `div` having `t` as their `class` attribute and at least one `<span>` tag inside and then it gets the array of webelement after the first position

Answer (score 0):

Below xpath:

```
//div[position()>1 and @class='t' and .//span ]
```

clearly specifying that the div should contains class='t', a span tag and its position should be greater than 1. There is no span tag in 2nd div. So that above xpath prints result from third div.

Mean while the Below xpath:

```
//div[position()>2 and @class='t' and .//span ]
```

also specifying that the div should contains class='t', a span tag and its position should be greater than 2. Means result starts from again third div.

div in third position is

```
 <div class='t'><span>2</span></div>
```

It contains class='t' and a span tag, and also position of div is greater than 2.

Comment: so it first apply `position()` and then check for other conditions, right?